# Licode: Publishing Stream has failed after successful ICE checks

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-14.04, webrtc, licode

I'm following the guide on [Licode page](http://lynckia.com/licode/install.html)

I have installed everything on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have configure ssl for licode and erizo controller in `licode_config.js` file to make the example works. Every other configurations i just keep them un-touch.

I have run the basic example but i cannot make a video conference.

Tracing google chrome console log, i catched:

```
WARNING:  Publishing Stream 665544631310986500 has failed after successful ICE checks
DEBUG:  Event: stream-failed
Stream Failed, act accordingly
DEBUG:  Received a removeStream for 665544631310986500 and it has not been registered here, ignoring.
INFO:  Stream unpublished
```

It's looks like i have to configure STUN or something in configuration of licode to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

After reading several articles on Licode website and their community. I find out that, the issue just because my server is an Azure VPS - not a local computer. It has public IP and private IP so I have to set `config.erizoController.publicIP`, `config.erizoAgent.publicIP` to the public IP of the server.

Also Azure vps close all ports by default (except some ports i have already opened). Because of that, i have to open suitable port range and setting the `config.erizo.minport`, `config.erizo.maxport` in `licode_config.js` file. The port range i use: 30000-31000.

The valuable reference: http://discourse.lynckia.com/t/running-licode-in-azure/29